# Xcode is running from a volume that does not support ownership. Please move Xcode to one that does

Tags: osx-mavericks, xcode

I tried to install XCODE 6.1 using dmg file.

But it get following error.

how to fix it ?

I am using 
OS X version 10.9.4

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run Xcode from pendrive, or external harddisk ?

Comment: i just copy the DMG file in my Downloads, and after that i double click on it, it create a Device name Xcode from where i double click on Xcode,so its from system like other dmg files did

Comment: It might help you https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6561199?start=0&tstart=0, its a problem of harddisk ownership, not xcode, even its not related to programming.

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed it.

1. Mount Xcode
2. Use `diskutil list` to find is where Xcode mounted
3. `sudo diskutil enableOwnership /dev/diskNsM` 
   (for example: `/dev/disk1s2`)

   [image: My console: Screen_Shot_0027_06_13_at_20_10_20]

Comment: I have an error message telling me : "Error enountered enabling user/group ownership: A disk with a mount point is required (-69854)"

Comment: @Pierre Try verify the volume after enable ownership : diskutil verifyVolume [drive identifier]
Ex: diskutil verifyVolume /

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error: “/Volumes/SSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim is not owned by root.”

Answer (score 0):

Finally fix it

Step i follow

Copy the Dmg file in my downloads (system)

Double click on it,it create a temp mount device,
[image]
Open the Xcode mount device,

Copy the Xcode

paste in Application,
[image]

its works